# Navigation in SwiftUI-apps run in iOS 14.5 beta is broken. Is there any way to fix it?

Tags: ios, swiftui

My published SwiftUI-app is using double column layout in iPad. With the release of iOS 14.5 and iPadOS 14.5 betas Apple has introduced undocumented changes to NavigationView behaviour and that causes some really buggy experience especially if the app used in spliview-mode.

I have found no way that my app could offer a bug free experience and support both iPhone and iPad with double column layout in upcoming iOS 14.5. With 14.4 all was fine. This is really bad and frustrating.

I have tried adding .isDetailLink(false) to NavigationLinks in View2 and View3 in my code example and at first that seems to correct the issues, but then I noticed that it will cause other problems like nonfunctional NavigationLinks.

I have also tried different ways to change the navigationViewStyle between Stacked and DoubleColumn depending on the horizontalSizeClass, but they all introduce other issues. It seems that there is no good way to change the .navigationViewStyle on the fly during the App lifetime.

Can you think any other way to solve this problem?

Here is a simple example how you can reproduce the issues:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {

            NavigationView{
                    View1()
                    Text("Select View")
            }
            .navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
    }
}

struct View1: View {

    var body: some View {

        List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: View2(),
                label: {
                    Text("Show View2")
            })
        }
    }
}

struct View2: View {

    var body: some View {

            List {
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: View3(),
                    label: {
                        Text("Navigate to View3")
                })
            }
    }
}

struct View3: View {

    var body: some View {

        List {
            NavigationLink(
                destination: Text("View4"),
                label: {
                    Text("Navigate to View4")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And here are images to show the problems:

[image]

Comment: If it is worked before and does not work in beta then file a bug to Apple, proposed workarounds if any could stop working in release drop.

Comment: Unfortunately Apple made a lot of mistakes inside 14.5.
IE: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/677333